# Softmax variant based on rank of vector indices

Tags: softmax

Given a $K$-dimensional real-valued vector $\mathbf{z} = (z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_K)$, I know that the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) returns a vector $\sigma(\mathbf{z})$ with positive elements summing to 1 via the following formula:

$$
\sigma(\mathbf{z})_j = \frac{e^{z_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^K e^{z_k}}, j = 1, \ldots, K
$$

Recently a colleague mentioned to me a variant of the softmax function, which I'll call $\sigma'(\cdot)$, that takes the following form:

$$
\sigma'(\mathbf{z})_j = \frac{\alpha^{r(\mathbf{z}, j)}}{\sum_{k=1}^K \alpha^{r(\mathbf{z}, k)}}, j = 1, \ldots, K
$$

Here, $\alpha > 0$ is a constant and $r(\mathbf{z}, j)$ is the rank of $z_j$ within the vector $\mathbf{z}$, so the smallest value takes rank 1, the second smallest rank 2, and so on. The largest index takes rank $K$.

Does this softmax variant (or a similar one based on the ranks of a vector's values instead of the values themselves) have a name, and is it used in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find this variant after quite a bit of Googling, Binging, Duckduckgoing... whoever uses it probably keeps it to themselves.

I found this paper on [Time series forecasting using a weighted cross-validation
evolutionary artificial neural network ensemble](http://repositorium.sdum.uminho.pt/bitstream/1822/24678/1/CVENN.pdf) by Donate et al. (Neurocomputing, 2013) where as an alternative to softmax weighting they use rank-based weight in the same way as in the $\sigma^\prime$ where they set $\alpha = e$;  (2.7182...) but that's about it.

I suspect you know of the [hierarchical softmax](https://yinwenpeng.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/hierarchical-softmax-in-neural-network-language-model/) function as a variant of the softmax (or *normalized exponential*) but this is not related to ranks. A distant relation I can see is with the *softrank* function by [Taylor et al.](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/63585/SoftRankWsdm08Submitted.pdf), which is the normalized discounted cumulative gain (see [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/denzho/nips/papers/gprank.pdf) for an application in a GP setting).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is used in practice, generally in winner-take-all situation or situation where you want to assign 1 (close to) to maximum value and 0 (close to) to all others. And it is still called `softmax`.

If you think about it, the value for $\sigma'(\mathbf{z})_K$ will be very close to 1 and value for all others will be close to 0. See this paper titled "Softmax to Softassign: Neural Network Algorithms for Combinatorial Optimization" for more information:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anand_Rangarajan/publication/2458489_Softmax_to_Softassign_Neural_Network_Algorithms_for_Combinatorial_Optimization/links/0deec5214b1cb9dbde000000.pdf#page=6

Comment: Regarding your statement in the second paragraph, the highest ranking elements is only selected with high probability for large $\alpha$ -- note that all elements are selected with equal probability for $\alpha=1$ and the smallest element is more likely with $\alpha < 1$. Unless I missed it, the linked paper appears to only use the standard softmax ($m_j = \frac{\text{exp}(\beta X_j)}{\sum_{i=1}^I \text{exp}(\beta X_i)}$ on Page 6). Is there somewhere in that paper where you saw a softmax variant based on the ranking of elements?

Comment: On page 6, they are increasing the value of $\beta$ for each $m_{i}$. In your case, if you are assuming $\alpha$ is probability, then yes, the lowest possible value will be close to 1. Basically, what your function is doing is that it is making the value of maxima/minima equal to 1 and rest of the elements 0. Does this help? Or you already knew this but wanted to see if there is a name for such softmax variant ?

Comment: I certainly understand what $\sigma'(\cdot)$ is doing, but I'm wondering if it has a name and is widely used. I still don't see how the example on Page 6 is related to my question -- the same $\beta$ value is being used to compute each $m_i$ value in a given iteration (though $\beta$ is changed between iterations of Procedure A on that page); further, the rank of the elements isn't mentioned on Page 6.

Comment: hmm i see. Then yes, even I couldn't find anything.